# Can "Free" be a noun? And what does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, nouns, word-usage, vocabulary

I saw this sentence when I was studying British Culture.

"William Shakespeare composed plays that broke FREE of England's past style of plays and theatre."

I was quite confused about the meaning of "Free" in this situation. I looked up the dictionaries but couldn't find any meaning.

Comment: Free is not a noun here. Wind would be a noun.

Comment: *Free* in *break free* is an adjective and appears in an example sentence in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/free) sense 2.1. "Broke away from the constrictions of the past style."

Comment: However, *free* **can** be a noun: "He came to enslave the free" (those people who were free).

Comment: Thanks for your help. By the way, is it possible to say that "break free" is a phrasal verb? Or something like that?

Comment: I recommend you visit [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). For basic questions like this ELL is a more suitable place.